# Using cakephp how do you display an image stored in the database in a foreach loop?

Tags: php, database, loops, cakephp, foreach

I'm new to Cakephp and I wanted to know how to echo an image from the database in a foreach loop?
How would I do this? What is the right way?
All my images are in the webroot folder.

```
<?php if ( isset($beefwellington) ){ ?>
       <?php foreach ($beefwellington as $wellington): ?>
        <h1><?php echo $wellington['Beef']['genre']; ?></h1>
        <h2><?php echo $wellington['Beef']['story']; ?></h2>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            <?php } ?>
```

This is what I tried:

```
<?php echo $html->image('app/webroot/img' .$wellington['Beef']['picture'],    array('alt' => 'story image'));
```

In my database the the images are stored like this 'pumkin.jpg'

Comment: I don't see any images in your code example. What did you try? What's in the database? The actual RAW image-data? Or a URL to the image? Or a filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your images on app/webtoot/img folder, then you just have to write like this:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image($wellington['Beef']['picture'], array('alt' => 'story image')); ?>
```